# Laravel filter resource controller - just accessable for owner

Tags: laravel, filter, controller, resources

An easy example to tell you what is my problem:
I have a Phone model an this belongsTo one user and one user hasMany phones.

In my routes.php I have a `Route::resource('phones', 'PhoneController')` so I can access a specific phone by the  following url localhost/phones/5.

These phones should be just visible for the owner, so I could check in every method in the PhoneController (show, store, edit, update) if the current user is the real owner of this phone but I think there are better ways like using filters directly in Routes.php to filter these things out and I don't need redundant checks.

Maybe you understand the problem and can help me solving this problem in an elegant way.

Comment: Did you able to get it ?

Comment: Hey, sorry it took me a bit time to test a bit out. I changed `Route::parameter` to `Route::input`, but I get `Missing argument 3 for {closure}()`

Comment: It's probably in you filter's third param, `function($request, $route, $param){}`, `$param` will catch the `id`.

Comment: Finally I got it working. I had the singular term in `Route::input`so it couldn't get the correct parameter. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may put this `_constructor` in your Controller:

```php
class PhoneController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $methodsToBeFiltered = array('show', 'store', 'edit', 'update');
        $id = Route::parameter('phone');
        $this->beforeFilter('filtername:' . $id, array('only' => $methodsToBeFiltered));
    }
}
```

Make sure you have declared the filte (`filtername`) in the `filters.php` file. I have used `phone` as the resource name if it doesn't match then run `php artisan routes` from your terminal and find the `url` parameter name for that route.

Comment: Thanks, that looks perfectly! But I'm not pretty sure how I can set a parameter to the filter. The documentary says something about it, but they doesn't explain how to use these parameters. http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters `Route::filter('age', function($route, $request, $value)` What should I use these for? Where can I set my phone id? And how do I get it in the constructor? The index method for example doesn't even have an id.

Comment: Check the updated answer, replace the `parameter` with real parameter.

Comment: Okay, I think the last problem is to get the phone id already in the controller. Maybe you have a quick tip for this aswell?

Comment: Phone `id` in the controller from where ?

Comment: It is usually given by the methods `public function show($id)` So it is localhost/phone/{id}